# Adding akka dependencies to osgi container

Tags: java, osgi, akka, eclipse-virgo

I use `osgi` container (`virgo`) [i'm not very good in that].

I added a dependency to my `pom.xml`

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.typesafe.akka</groupId>
    <artifactId>akka-osgi_2.10</artifactId>
    <version>2.2-M3</version>
</dependency>
```

I put `akka-osgi_2.10-2.2-M3.jar` to my lib/deploy folder to `OSGI` server (to `myserver/repository/usr`).

I added dummy actor to my code base:

```
import akka.actor.UntypedActor;

public class ManagerActor extends UntypedActor {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Object o) throws Exception {
        // ...
    }
}
```

I build and start my application.

And as result I have the following exceptions in my log (it complains to `version="0.0.0"`):

```
.. failed. org.eclipse.virgo.kernel.osgi.framework.UnableToSatisfyBundleDependenciesException: Unable to satisfy dependencies of bundle 'com.
com.mycompnay.mything-security' at version '1.0.1.BUILD-SNAPSHOT': Cannot resolve: com.mycompany.mything-security
    Resolver report:
        An Import-Package could not be resolved. Resolver error data <Import-Package: akka.actor; version="0.0.0">. Caused by missing constrai
nt in bundle <com.mycompany.mything-security_1.0.1.BUILD-SNAPSHOT>
             constraint: <Import-Package: akka.actor; version="0.0.0">
```

I go to my `template.mf` file, which is used to generate final `MANIFEST.MF` file. To specify the range of versions for AKKA lib I use. Putting there:

```
Import-Template: 
 akka.actor.*;version="[2.2.0.M3, 2.3)"

Import-Package: 
 akka.actor;version="[2.2.0.M3, 2.3)"
```

Then rebuild and start app.

But in console it complains to akka versions (complains to `version="[2.2.0.M3,2.3.0)"` now):

```
        An Import-Package could not be resolved. Resolver error data <Import-Package: akka.actor; version="[2.2.0.M3,2.3.0)">. Caused by missi
ng constraint in bundle <com.mycompany.mything-security_1.0.1.BUILD-SNAPSHOT>
             constraint: <Import-Package: akka.actor; version="[2.2.0.M3,2.3.0)">
```

**Q: what's wrong?**

---

Also I tried to add this line: to `Import-Bundle`:

```
Import-Bundle: 
 ...
 com.typesafe.akka.osgi;version="[2.2.0.M3, 2.3)"
```

Then I have it in the log (now it complains to com.typesafe.akka.osgi version):

```
.. failed. org.eclipse.virgo.kernel.deployer.core.DeploymentException: Unable to satisfy dependencies of bundle 'com.mycompany.mything-security
' at version '1.0.1.BUILD-SNAPSHOT': Import-Bundle with symbolic name 'com.typesafe.akka.osgi' in version range '[2.2.0.M3, oo)' could not be
satisfied
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason was:

I need to put `akka-actor_2.10-2.2-M3.jar` (along with akka-osgi_2.10-2.2-M3.jar) to my osgi (virgo) deploy folder.

So, we should NOT do it manually but with help of maven (in order not to miss some jar that comes along with expecting one).